# Will Cygnus do anything special when it "looses its NACHOS"?

Tags: earth-observation, payload-deployment, nanosatellite, cygnus

CBS News' [NASA's new "NACHOS" instrument could help predict volcanic eruptions](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/nasa-nachos-predict-volcanic-eruptions/) explains that this nanosatellite will be deployed from the Cygnus spacecraft [launched February 19, 2022](https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-sets-coverage-opens-virtual-experience-for-next-cargo-launch) after it departs the ISS and before it reenters Earth's atmosphere.

**Question:** Will Cygnus simply deploy it with a low velocity without fanfare or special maneuvering or will it have some series of specific maneuvers necessary for deployment?

[image: NACHOS, with its solar panels unfolded. CREDITS: LOS ALAMOS NATIONAL LABORATORY/LOGAN OTT]

> NACHOS, with its solar panels unfolded. CREDITS: LOS ALAMOS NATIONAL LABORATORY/LOGAN OTT

[Source](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/nasa-nachos-predict-volcanic-eruptions/)

Comment: iirc Cygnus usually has an "extended mission" post ISS de-berth doing all sorts of stuff (i.e., cubesat deploy)

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 oh that's right! I think that there's one described here: [Was anything special done for the Cygnus OA-9 launch to give it so much extra fuel?
](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29460/12102)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

Not a lot to go on.

The best I found was on Nanoracks own website:

> Deployment from Cygnus
>
> After performing resupply and station keeping operations, the Cygnus vehicle un-berths from the
> International Space Station. CubeSat deployment from the NRCSD-E occurs prior to the
> destructive re-entry of the Cygnus vehicle at an altitude above the ISS (specific altitude
> determined by Northrop Grumman pending programmatic decisions). Nominally, this new
> altitude is around 450km, but can range from 445km to 500km depending on Cygnus fuel capacity
> and conjunction analysis.
>
> Cygnus operations are managed by Northrop Grumman ground controllers.
>
> Once a CubeSat
> deployment window has been established, ground controllers send the deployment command
> to the NRCSD-E.
>
> This deployment command electrically activates the three HRDMs restraining
> the middle door and deploys CubeSats from the two middle silos.
>
> - There may be more than one
>   CubeSat in a single silo, depending on the form factor and mission complement.
> - Deployment of
>   the satellite(s) is captured by Cygnus external cameras to verify good deployment.
> - After deploying the middle silos, ground controllers wait three hours before opening
>   the next door, and so forth.

[image]

> ABOVE THE ISS SATELLITE LAUNCH SERVICES
>
> Deploying Satellites at 465-500 km Orbits
>
> Nanoracks provides CubeSat and Smallsat launch services for payloads that require orbits higher than the International Space Station (ISS). Satellites are deployed from the Nanoracks CubeSat Deployer (NRCSD), mounted directly onto Panel 5 of the Cygnus expendable cargo spacecraft which is placed in orbit by Northrop Grumman’s Antares Rocket.
>
> Upon launch, Cygnus remains at the ISS for about 30 days, which is then released and raised to an orbit of 450-500km (50-100km higher than ISS). Once this maneuver is complete, the satellites are deployed at 51.6° inclination, before the Cygnus moves into a re-entry burn.

Given that Nanoracks offers three options, thats the only one that fits this profile:

> Want to launch a satellite?
>
> Nanoracks CubeSat Deployer In Orbit
>
> - Deploy at 415km
> - Deploy from the ISS at 415km (51.6° inclination)
> - Frequent launches available on all International Space Station (ISS) cargo resupply vehicles – from 1U to ESPA-class satellites.
>
> ISS SATELLITE LAUNCH
>
> Nanoracks
>
> - Deploy at 460-500km
> - Deploy from above the ISS at 460-500km (51.6° inclination)
>
> Give your satellite that extra boost, deploy. directly from Cygnus. We were the first use a cargo vehicle for a dual purpose.
>
> ABOVE THE ISS LAUNCH
>
> Nanoracks
>
> - Deploy at 500-600km
> - Deploy from a SpaceX or PSLV rideshare at 500-600km (sun-synchronous)

Other info is for the deployer itself:

[image]

*(Thought I was looking at Sea Sparrow at first..)*

[image]

https://nanoracks.com/wp-content/uploads/Nanoracks-External-Cygnus-Deployer-E-NRCSD-IDD.pdf

https://nanoracks.com/wp-content/uploads/Nanoracks-CubeSat-Deployer-NRCSD-IDD.pdf

> The E-NRCSD is attached to the outside of the Cygnus spacecraft and deploys CubeSats roughly 30 miles above the ISS after the Cygnus completes its mission and unberths from the space station.

https://nanoracks.com/northrop-grumman-resupply-mission-to-iss/

Example deployment: 'boiiing'

> Mar 29, 2018
>
> The Integrated Solar and Reflectarray Antenna (ISARA) spacecraft deploys from NanoRack’s external Cygnus deployer platform on December 6 from an altitude of 280 miles above Earth.

Theres a few NASA links but so many are 404 these days.

Suffice to say the real details are with NG, and those are harder to find.